# ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5 when I debug TensorFlow programs using VScode with the python extension?

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I have installed VSCode with the Python extension on my Ubuntu system. I have also installed TensorFlow 0.9, CUDA 7.5 and cuDNN library correctly.

However, when I debug the tensorflow program using VSCode, it will give an error importing tensorflow (import tensorflow) as below:

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can be sure all the libraries have all been installed successfully. Because I can debug and run Python programs in VSCode, and I can also run tensorflow programs using the Ubuntu Terminal.

Besides, when I import tensorflow from the Ubuntu Terminal, it gives output as follows:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

As you can see, it didn't use the lib 'libcudart.so.7.5'.

I have also checked the CUDA path in ~/.bashrc, which is as bellow:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-7.5
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin
```

Since my CUDA was installed in the path '/usr/local/cuda-7.5', and I can also find the 'libcudart.so.7.5' lib in that path, I don't think there is any error.

So what is the problem? Why importing from Terminal, there is no error, but there is such an error when importing from vscode? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what is VSCode, but these kind of errors usually happen due to difference in environment. IE, your Terminal and VSCode have different values for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Thank you. I have solved my problem finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem after searching and reading many web pages. The method is as bellows:

First, link the CUDA library using the following command:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

Then, I can import tensorflow in VSCode. However, there is still one error, which is as bellow:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:99] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:1562] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
```

Although the program can run, it seems that the program cannot find the cuDNN library. Then I found the cuDNN library was not installed correctly on my Ubuntu system. I modified my installation using the following commands:

```
cd ~/cuda
sudo cp include/cudnn.h /usr/include
sudo cp lib64/libcudnn* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo chmod a+r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn*
```

Here, '~/cuda' is the path of my cuDNN installation files.

Finally, after all these steps, I can import tensorflow and debug my program in VSCode now.